# How to round off gap between some arbitrary numbers?

Tags: algorithm, rounding

I am trying to devise an algorithm to find the best possible rounded number of some semi-random numbers. In my case, inputs are like the note duration in music theory.
So as an instance, if the inputs are somethings like:

```
109 102 212 196 99 802
```

then outputs would be like:

```
100 100 200 200 100 800
```

PS: Actually I want to write a code to convert a singing track to music sheets.

Comment: You could probably start by taking the base 10 logarithm of all the numbers.

Comment: `(2^n)*(smallest gap)` is going to give you 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, 256, 512, 1024 ... That won't be anything like 200, 400, 800.

Comment: : |
suppose the smallest gap is 100.

Answer (score 2):

Actually I wanted to write a code to convert a singing track to a sheets music. for that, I found intervals between adjacent notes then I need the algorithm to round off these intervals.
I've done this and it works well I think.
First I found the value of the major gap for example in " 102 103 402 409 390 398 100 200 408" the major gap is something near 400 (average of 402 409 390 398 408) then I put the duration of it as 1 and compare the other with it.
for 102 duration will be 0.25 and so on.

Edited: Frist I used some python libraries to process the .mp3 file and find the moment of changing of frequency and its corresponding duration in milisec. Since these times are not exact I need to round off so I can assign them one of the note notations.

```
def roundOff(diffs):
        global major_element, ref_offset, divide_flag, measured_time, measured_note
        major_element = findMajor(diffs)
        for element in diffs:
            divide_flag = False
            measured_time = 0
            measured_note = 0
            note_duration.append(noteFinder(element, ref_offset))
        return note_duration
```

The above function gets gaps as input and returns its corresponding note duration.
I found the major gap as follow:

```
def findMajor(diffs):
    diffs_copy = diffs.copy()
    diffs_copy.sort()
    this = 0
    for element in diffs_copy:
        if isNear(element, this):
            temp_this = (this*elements_in_gap[this] + element)/(elements_in_gap[this] + 1)
            elements_in_gap[this] += 1
            elements_in_gap[temp_this] = elements_in_gap.pop(this)
            this = temp_this
        else:
            this = element
            elements_in_gap[this] = 1

    return max(elements_in_gap, key = element_in_gap.get)
```

First, it sorts the list of gaps and put 'this' as the representative value of the gap we want to check others with (initial is 0), in each step, it checks if the new gap is near 'this' then modify 'this' and increments number of gaps in 'this' set, but if it's not near, change 'this' to new element and initial number of new 'this' (: |) to 1 and do same.
Finally, return key with the most amount of value as a major-gap.

isNear function is like this:

```
def isNear(a, b):
    if a < b+b*tolerance and a > b-b*tolerance:
        return True
    return False
```

In this case, it's appropriate to set tolerance as 0.1.
noteFinder finds the note of each gap regarding the major gap as 1 (ref_offset).

```
def noteFinder(diff_time, offset):
    global measured_time, measured_note, divide_flag, major_element
    if isNear(diff_time, measured_time):
        return measured_note
    else:
        if not divide_flag:
            if diff_time > measured_time:
                measured_time += offset*major_element
                measured_note += offset
                return noteFinder(diff_time, offset)
            else:
                offset /= 2
                measured_time -= offset*major_element
                measured_note -= offset
                divide_flag = True
                return noteFinder(diff_time, offset)
        else:
            offset /= 2
            if diff_time > measured_time:
                measured_time += offset*major_element
                measured_note += offset
                return noteFinder(diff_time, offset)
            else:
                measured_time -= offset*major_element
                measured_note -= offset
                return noteFinder(diff_time, offset)
```

It adds offset to measured-note and offset*major-gap-value to measured-time in each step (firstly, offset is 1 as mentioned) till its gap-value is lower than measured-time then it will turn on divid_flag to divide offset by 2 in each step and tries to be near the gap-value, then it returns meatured-note.

It is my proposed scheme if you have a better one please let me know.

Comment: Your problem is clearer with that context (and more interesting.) Could you post some code that does this and explain how this solves your problem?